# How to listen the name of a pressed key using the Keyboard module in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to get the name of the key pressed using the Python [keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

I was able to register the hotkey in the following way.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import keyboard 

class threadingGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None

    def executeHotKey(self,abc):
        print("key pressed " + abc)

    def time_count(self):
        while not self.stop_flag:
            time.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            #add hotkey
            keyboard.add_hotkey('a', self.executeHotKey, args=('a'))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('b', self.executeHotKey, args=('b'))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('c', self.executeHotKey, args=('c')) 
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.time_count)
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()


    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

        self.stop_flag=True
        self.thread.join()

t = threadingGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

However, the above code won't respond unless I register the hotkey in advance.

I want to get the name even for keystrokes that don't register as hotkeys.

This is because I want to have a TextInput so that users can register hotkeys in the GUI.

In the Keyboard module, can I listen for keystrokes that are not registered as hotkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `keyboard.record` function as shown [here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-keyboard-python).

For example,

```
events = keyboard.record('esc')
```

recorded all my keystrokes until I pressed the escape key. `keyboard.record` returns a list of `KeyboardEvent` objects which contain the names (as well as some other data) for the pressed keys.

In the case of what I typed, `events[0].name` returns 'h' which was the first key I typed, `events[2].name` returns `e` which was the second key I typed, etc.

Note that key up and key down are recorded as separate `KeyboardEvent`'s so you will likely want to filter them as it will contain doubles of each letter (assuming the name is all you are concerned with).

Alternate approach: 
If you aren't married to `keyboard`, I suggest checking out `pynput`, I've had some great success building keyloggers using this package.

Comment: Thank you, it worked well! I will also try to use pynput as you recommend.